# Condition on the existence of the object in the User-defined function, not in the Global environment in R

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I'm building the user defined function in R.

I want to make condition statement with the object existence.

If the object `variable` is defined in the function, then print `TRUE`, or else, then `FALSE`.

In this case, it was recommended to use `exists` function. If the `variable` was not defined previously, the function will print `FALSE`.

However, if the object is not defined inside the `function`, the `exists` function automatically looked for global environment. If I defined the object in the global environment previously, then `exists` function will always print `TRUE`.

I want to make the condition only depending on the environment in the function, not on the global environment.

I would really appreciate for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the "where" and "envir" arguments to the `exists` function, see `?exists`.

```
f <- function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x)) y <- x + 2
  exists(x = "y", where = -1)
}
f("a")
[1] FALSE
f(1)
[1] TRUE
```

Alternatively, using the `envir` argument:

```
f <- function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x)) y <- x + 2
  exists(x = "y", envir = rlang::current_env())
}
```

However, in practical cases it might be preferable to make a `NULL` variable instead, often paired with a user defined null coalescing operator (%||%) to specify a default value later.

```
f <- function(x){
  y <- if(is.numeric(x)) x + 2 else NULL
  !is.null(y)
}
# same as
f <- function(x){
  y <- if(is.numeric(x)) x + 2
  !is.null(y)
}
```